# Scala type conversion error, need help!

Tags: scala

I am getting a weird error when trying to use a Java map in Scala. This is the snippet of code

```
val value:Double = map.get(name)
  if (value eq null) map.put(name, time) else map.put(name, value + time)
```

the map is defined as

```
val map=new ConcurrentHashMap[String,Double]
```

and this is the error I am getting

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Double
required: ?{val eq: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
both method double2Double in object Predef of type (Double)java.lang.Double
and method doubleWrapper in object Predef of type (Double)scala.runtime.RichDouble
are possible conversion functions from Double to ?{val eq: ?}
if (value eq null) map.put(name, time)
```

I am new to Scala so I am having a hard time parsing the stacktrace. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `map.get(name)` will not return `null` in the case when `name` key is not present in the map. It will instead return a `Double(0.0)`.

Second, the error that you see is because scala is trying to implicitly convert the returned Double value to a type suitable for the `eq` comparision and it finds more than one implicit conversions in the scope.

The better way to do what you are doing is

```
if (map contains name) map.put(name, map.get(name) + time) 
else map.put(name, time)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Double
required: ?{val eq: ?}
```

The problem here is that `eq` is only defined for classes extending `AnyRef` and extended by `Null`, but `Double` extends `AnyVal` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel wrote, part of the problem trying to write in a Java style with Double comes from the fact that `Double` in Scala is `scala.Double` and not `java.lang.Double`. If you wanted to program in Java style you would have to go along the following lines:

```
//
// a) Java style, with concurrency problem
//
import java.lang.{Double=>JDouble}
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
val map = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, JDouble]
def update(name: String, time: Double) {
  val value: JDouble = map.get(name)
  if (value eq null)
    map.put(name, time)
  else
    map.put(name, JDouble.valueOf(value.doubleValue + time))
}
update("foo", 42.0d)
update("foo", 41.0d)
assert(map.get("foo") == 83.0d)
```

Scala 2.8 contains a Scala wrapper for `ConcurrentMap`s, so you can easily avoid the problem of `java.lang.Double` vs `scala.Double`. I'll keep the program structure for a moment.

```
//
// b) Scala style, with concurrency problem.
//
import collection.JavaConversions._
import collection.mutable.ConcurrentMap
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
val map: ConcurrentMap[String, Double] = new ConcurrentHashMap[String,Double]()
def update(name: String, time: Double) {
  map.get(name) match {
    case None => map.put(name, time)
    case Some(value) => map.put(name, value + time)
  }
}
update("foo", 42.0d)
update("foo", 41.0d)
assert(map("foo") == 83.0d)
```

In variant b) above there is neither the problem of representing the missing value as 0.0d nor the problem that `java.lang.Double` doesn't play nicely with operators and boxing. But both versions a) and b) are questionable regarding their concurrency behaviour. Mansoor's code uses a `ConcurrentHashMap`, which has the purpose of allowing for concurrent access to the map. In the original version of the code there is a chance that an update to the map is lost between getting the old `value` and storing `value + time`.
Variant c) below tries to avoid that problem.

```
//
// c) Scala style, hopefully safe for concurrent use ;)
//
import collection.JavaConversions._
import collection.mutable.ConcurrentMap
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
val map: ConcurrentMap[String, Double] = new ConcurrentHashMap[String,Double]()

def update(name: String, time: Double) {
  val valueOption: Option[Double] = map.putIfAbsent(name, time)
  def replace(value: Double) {
    val replaced = map.replace(name, value, value + time)
    if (!replaced) {
      replace(map(name))
    }
  }
  valueOption foreach { replace(_) }
}

update("foo", 42.0d)
update("foo", 41.0d)
assert(map("foo") == 83.0d)
```